# Laravel class not found after migrating the file

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel Stapler for image purposes and after migrating the new table, I attempt to `artisan migrate:refresh` afterwards and I am shown this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>    Class 'AddPhotoFieldsToStaffTable' not found

However, I can see the file within my migration's folder and using `php artisan migrate`, before trying to `--refresh` it, it successfully migrated!

The file that was generated is:

```
class AddPhotoFieldsToStaffTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Make changes to the table.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('staff', function(Blueprint $table) {

            $table->string('photo_file_name')->nullable();
            $table->integer('photo_file_size')->nullable()->after('photo_file_name');
            $table->string('photo_content_type')->nullable()->after('photo_file_size');
            $table->timestamp('photo_updated_at')->nullable()->after('photo_content_type');

        });

    }

    /**
     * Revert the changes to the table.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('staff', function(Blueprint $table) {

            $table->dropColumn('photo_file_name');
            $table->dropColumn('photo_file_size');
            $table->dropColumn('photo_content_type');
            $table->dropColumn('photo_updated_at');

        });
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `composer dumpautoload` solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the command

`composer dump-autoload`